# Get all files from a directory and put them in an array

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, unix

I have an assignment I am working on, but I am having a problem getting it started. Some of the assignment text is below, which can help guild me in the right direction.

My main problem is getting the list of files into an array. I think if I can do that, the rest should be easy. I can push the files into an array that are passed as arguments, but I don't know how to get all the files from a directory, broken up into each file into an array.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why do you need to get all files from a directory? The assignment doesn't say to do that.

Comment: That maybe that I have the wrong idea of what the question is asking. They way I interpret it, is that he want's to put in into his directory and run the script to organize the files into types. these types would be regular file, symbolic link, directory, or other. I have to do other commands on this script, but I don't want to give much away.

Is there another way of interpreting this task? maybe something I am missing?

Comment: None of what you just said is part of the assignment that you quoted in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to *Benjamin W's comment*:
Just use `files=(*)`

Or, if you want to include hidden files and don't want do get in trouble with empty folders, use this (thanks to *Fred's comment*):

```
shopt -s nullglob dotglob
files=(*)
```

Comment: Not my DV, but this is a cumbersome way to say `files=(*)`

Comment: sure, I just didn't want to steal your solution.

Comment: You need `shopt -s nullglob dotglob` to (1) have the expansion include files with names beginning with a dot and (2) avoid the glob expanding to `*` if there are no matching files.

Comment: Thanks Fred, I added your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob
arr=(/home/*)

for ((i=0; i<${#arr[@]}; i++)); do
    echo "${arr[$i]}"
done
```

Comment: Without `shopt -s dotglob`, files with names that begin with a dot will not be taken into account (which may or may not be what is required in any specific case).

Comment: yes...+1 for the extra clarification . question didn't mention any specific case...just removed all dot files !

Answer (score 0):

This script checks if it has been given any parameters (`(( $# == 0 ))`), and if not, it uses `set -- "$PWD"` to set the first positional parameter to the current directory, `.`.

After that, `for f` (which is short for `for f in "$@"`) loops over all the parameters for processing.

```
#!/bin/bash

(( $# == 0 )) && set -- "$PWD"
for f; do
    # Do something with f
done
```

Comment: It says to use `.` if no parameters are given, not all (non-hidden) files in the current directory.

Comment: @melpomene I interpreted that as "everything in `.`"... do you think it should be just the current working directory?

Comment: Yes, because it specifically refers to "file system objects" (which includes directories and other things), not just files.

Comment: Ah, thank you for your feedback. I think this will help me a lot. its easy to read code and you gave explanation, which I am very thankful for.